# onClick on img works but cannot dynamically attach the same even in JavaScript, what is wrong?

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events

The following code creates two `<img>` objects, one statically defined in html, with an event that works, and one defined in JavaScript that does not.  Obviously this can be done in JavaScript, so what is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function build() {
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src = "cat.jpg";
      img.onclick = "alert('yo')";
      document.getElementById("quiz").appendChild(img);
    return img;
   }
   </script>
  </head>
  <body onLoad="build()">
    <div id="quiz">
      <img src="trex.jpg" onClick="alert('hello')"></img>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the onclick function to be a string. When you define an onclick parameter in HTML you give it a string, which can contain Javascript code.

When you are in javascript you must define a function that will be called when you click on the image.

You can pass an argument to the function which will be the event that triggered it. In the following case `e` will be the event.

```
  img.onclick = function (e){ alert(e); };
```

You can read more about the javascript formation at W3C: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

```js
var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = "http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=med";
  img.onclick = function(e) {
    alert(e);
  };
  document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```html
<img onclick="alert('hello')" src="http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg&size=med" />
```

Comment: but then how can I pass in the event?  In html I would write onClick="f(event)"